# File ready open error 55. Unable to open one file as binary and write into text file

Tags: vb6

I have an vb 6 project already working fine. but I just want to read a syncfile and read into an text file Unable to read on file and write into a text file. If I comment the writing process and read only syncfile than its working fine.

```
Sub ReadSyncFile(){
Dim iFile As Long
iFile = FreeFile
iFile2 = FreeFile
Open App.Path & "\sirt.txt" For Output As iFile2
Open SyncFile For Binary Access Read As iFile

Get iFile, , SyncHdr
wb.Visible = False

For icnt = 1 To MAX_PAGES
PBar = icnt
DoEvents
    If SyncHdr(icnt).OffsetStart > 1 Then
       Seek iFile, SyncHdr(icnt).OffsetStart
       Get iFile, , SyncPgs(icnt).pgHdr

       ReDim arWords(SyncPgs(icnt).pgHdr.nWords)
       Get iFile, , arWords

       For i = 0 To UBound(arWords)
           Print #iFile2, i, arWords(i).WrdNum; arWords(i).WrdText; arWords(i).WrdAudLen; arWords(i).WrdIsSync
       Next
       Close iFile2

       ReDim SyncPgs(icnt).arWrd(SyncPgs(icnt).pgHdr.nWords)
       SyncPgs(icnt).arWrd = arWords
    End If
    Next
    Close iFile
    Erase SyncHdr
    wb.Visible = True
    syncOpened = True
 End Sub
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling the `FreeFile` function before opening any files you get the same number returned (probably 1), and assigned to both iFile and iFile2. That is the source of your error. You are attempting to open both files with the same file number.

Change your code just a little to set iFile to FreeFile, the open a file, before you call FreeFile again.

```
Sub ReadSyncFile(){
Dim iFile As Long

iFile = FreeFile
Open SyncFile For Binary Access Read As iFile
iFile2 = FreeFile
Open App.Path & "\sirt.txt" For Output As iFile2

Get iFile, , SyncHdr
wb.Visible = False

For icnt = 1 To MAX_PAGES
    PBar = icnt
    DoEvents
    If SyncHdr(icnt).OffsetStart > 1 Then
        Seek iFile, SyncHdr(icnt).OffsetStart
        Get iFile, , SyncPgs(icnt).pgHdr

        ReDim arWords(SyncPgs(icnt).pgHdr.nWords)
        Get iFile, , arWords

        For i = 0 To UBound(arWords)
            Print #iFile2, i, arWords(i).WrdNum; arWords(i).WrdText; arWords(i).WrdAudLen; arWords(i).WrdIsSync
        Next
        Close iFile2

        ReDim SyncPgs(icnt).arWrd(SyncPgs(icnt).pgHdr.nWords)
        SyncPgs(icnt).arWrd = arWords
    End If
    Next
    Close iFile
    Erase SyncHdr
    wb.Visible = True
    syncOpened = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Jac. But I tried your solution and even I tried with assigning the different number instead of using freeFile but again getting the same error.

Comment: @varinder I didn't pay attention to you saying you were trying to write a binary file to a text file. Can you explain why you need to do that?